# Check dict values and randomize in python

Tags: python

I have a sorted dict as below -

```
check = {'id1':'01', 'id2':'03', 'id3':'03', 'id4':'10'}
```

I want to check the values in the above list in python codee and randomize the ids if values are same.

Expected output is `check2 = {'id1':'01', 'id3':'03', 'id2':'03', 'id4':'10'}` (randomize the ids which has the same values. Sometimes id2 in second position and sometimes id3 in second position)

Comment: Hello sss, please, provide your code

Comment: Its already sorted by value

Comment: How did it get sorted? It might be better to simply incorporate the randomizing into the sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your dictionary is sorted by values, you can use `itertools.groupby` to group by identical values.

Then use `random.sample` to shuffle the keys per group.

Finally generate a new dictionary from the list of keys:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from random import sample

keys = list(chain.from_iterable(sample((l:=list(g)), len(l))
                                for k,g in groupby(check, lambda x:check[x])))

check2 = {k: check[k] for k in keys}
```

example output:

```
{'id1': '01', 'id3': '03', 'id2': '03', 'id4': '10'}
```

intermediate result:

```
>>> keys
['id1', 'id3', 'id2', 'id4']
```

Comment: Try `for _, [*g] in groupby(check, check.get)`.

Comment: @sss you should do you describe. For example, check if the first two values are 0, if True you're in the first case (then the exact output you want is ambiguous to me), if False, do as above.